# cordova-app-loader on iOS in production 2016

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins, self-updating

I would like to be able to update my code faster than the time it takes Apple to release my application.

Luckily, my application is based on Cordova. I've also found [cordova-app-loader](https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-app-loader) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975542/cordova-phonegap-live-update-codebase).

My question is, for the date of writing, February 2015, does Apple still allow this behavior? Did anyone release a hybrid iOS application lately that can self-updates itself?